# C++ TCHAR[] to string

Tags: c++, string, tchar

I have this method which receives a path through a `TCHAR szFileName[]` variable, which contains something like `C:\app\...\Failed\`

I'd like to sort through it so I can verify if the name of the last folder on that path is in fact, "Failed"

I thought that using something like this would work:

```
std::wstring Path = szFileName;

string dirpath2;
dirpath2 = Path.substr(0,5);
```

But I get the following error:

> Error 6   error C2679: binary '=' : no
>   operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
>   (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Needless to say, I'm very new to C++, and I've been looking for an answer for a while now, but I haven't had any luck, so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you’re consistently using `wstring` (the wide character variant) or `string` (the “normal” variant).

Since you’re getting a `TCHAR` (which can be either `wchar_t` or `char`, depending on compiler flags), the appropriate type to use would be a `tstring`, but that doesn’t exist. However, you can define a typedef for it:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

Now you can consistently use the same string type, `tstring`, for all your operations.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand what goes on there.

am I supposed to do something like:
  
std::tstring Path = szFileName;

'cause if so, then I get the following error:

'tstring' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: You’re defining `tstring` yourself, and it’s not in the namespace `std` so when you use it, don’t prefix it with `std::`.

Comment: it seems to work but why do I get an error "initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'" when I try to use substr to store a part of the initial string on another string?

Comment: You are still using different string types! You need to use `tstring` consistently for both strings!

Answer (score 3):

`dirpath2` has to be a `std::wstring` as well. There are ways to convert between the two, but they involve changing the character encoding and that seems like more than you're asking for.

I like to simply not use TCHAR. Today, there is rarely is there a need to enable or disable the UNICODE macros and create both an ASCII and a Unicode version of a program. Just always use `wstring`, `wchar_t`, and the Windows API functions that end in 'W'.

If you're working on something where you don't have control over the above, Konrad's `typedef` answer is more practical than mine.